# onActivityResult doesn't work

Tags: android, android-intent

i used Google Place Autocomplete.
[Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete)

But the method "onActivityResult" did not be received any any results when a user has selected a place. And it don't run.
How fix ??
Thank you
[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VfYm.png)

Comment: In place of "this" use...MainActivity.this...it will help

Comment: post full source code